# send a file to multiple device at same time via python&bluez

Tags: python

i want send a file to multiple device at same time via python ...
my code :

```
import bluetooth
from lightblue import *
import select
import threading

def send(fileaddress,bladdress,pushport):
    client = obex.OBEXClient(bladdress, pushport)
    client.connect()
    client.put({"name": "test"}, open(fileaddress))

def StartSend(fileaddress,bladdress,pushport):
    t=threading.Thread(group=None,target=send, name=None, args=(fileaddress,bladdress,pushport))
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()
    t.join()


class MyDiscoverer(bluetooth.DeviceDiscoverer):

    def pre_inquiry(self):
        self.done = False

    def device_discovered(self, addr, device_class, name):
        print "%s - %s" % (addr, name)
        serv = bluetooth.find_service(name="OBEX Object Push", uuid=None, address=None)
        pushport = serv[0]['port']
        StartSend('/home/abbas/Desktop/eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz', addr, pushport)


    def inquiry_complete(self):
        self.done = True




if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = MyDiscoverer()
    d.find_devices(lookup_names = True)
    readfiles = [ d, ]
    while True:
        rfds = select.select( readfiles, [], [] )[0]

        if d in rfds:
            d.process_event()

        if d.done: break
```

but when first device detect and start send file to it all python script paused and wait that sending finish and next start to send another device ...

why ?

i use thread so why pause python process in send step ?

i use this site for these code :
http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x339.html

```
 To asynchronously detect nearby bluetooth devices, create a subclass of DeviceDiscoverer and override the pre_inquiry, device_discovered, and inquiry_complete methods. To start the discovery process, invoke find_devices, which returns immediately. pre_inquiry is called immediately before the actual inquiry process begins, and inquiry_complete is called as soon as the process completes.

MyDiscoverer exposes a fileno method, which allows it to be used with the select module. This provides a way for a single thread of control to wait for events on many open files at once, and greatly simplifies event-driven programs.

Call process_event to have the DeviceDiscoverer process pending events, which can be either a discovered device or the inquiry completion. When a nearby device is detected, device_discovered is invoked, with the address and device class of the detected device. If lookup_names was set in the call to find_devices, then name will also be set to the user-friendly name of the device. For more information about device classes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `StartSend` function joins the thread, which waits for the thread to finish. So, creating the thread was pointless. Try using `multiprocessing.ThreadPool` instead. Its not well documented but works the same as `multiprocessing.Pool`.